# Shopify API Draft Order, Order or Checkout with Custom Taxes

Tags: ruby, shopify, shopify-app

I'm stuck. Even though all the documentation says you can, I can't add custom taxes to a DraftOrder or a Checkout. But oddly enough I can with a regular order.

This is my code, and all I change is which object I hit either `Order` `DraftOrder` or `Checkout`

```
order = ShopifyAPI::Checkout.create({
line_items:
  [{variant_id: 7132271018031,
    quantity: 1,
    tax_lines: [
    {price: "11.55",
      rate: "0.07",
      title: "Todd's Tax"
    }],
  }],
    total_tax: "11.55"
})
```

And yes I have an active valid session. The order/checkout/draft order is being created, it just doesn't have the `tax_line` that I sent.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever resolce this?